# If $\gamma : J \mapsto M$ is a smooth curve in a smooth manifold M, then $\gamma'(t) \neq 0$ $\forall t \in J$ iff $d\gamma$ is injective.

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

If $\gamma : J \mapsto M$ is a smooth curve in a smooth manifold M, then $\gamma'(t) \neq 0$ $\forall t \in J$ iff $d\gamma$ is injective.

Here $J$ is just an open interval of $\mathbb{R}$

I'm just reading through Lee's book on smooth manifolds and this question pops up on page 78. Any help would be much appreciated!

Note : I don't understand how this map can be injective since each tangent space $T_{t}J$ has a zero element which the liner map $d_{j}$ will therefore send to zero. So $dj$ will send many elementsof $TJ$ to zero?

Comment: Sorry but what is $d\gamma$?

Comment: $d\gamma$ just represents the differential of $\gamma$. I.e $(d\gamma)(v)(f) := v(f(\gamma))$ where $v \in TJ$ and $f$ is a smooth function from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: If $\gamma'(t)\neq 0$ then the only vector that you send to zero is zero, i.e. $d\gamma(t)v=0$ if and only if $v=0$

Comment: But $d\gamma(0\cdot d/dt(t_0)) = d\gamma(0\cdot d/dt(t_1))$ and $0\cdot d/dt(t_0) \neq 0\cdot d/dt(t_1)$ since they are in $T_{t_0}$ and $T_{t_1}$ respectively.

Comment: Please clarify your notation. What is the symbol $0\cdot d/dt(t_0)$?

Comment: $d/dt(t_0)$ is a vector in vector space $T_{t_0}$ which spans it since it is one dimensional. Since it is a vector space $0\cdot d/dt(t_0)$ is me just scaling the vector by $0 \in \mathbb{R}$. Essentially my point that $d\gamma$ isn't injective since $TJ$ is the disjoint union of the $T_tJ$ which each contain an element that $d\gamma$ will send to zero.

Comment: If I understood correctly you notation, you are applying $d\gamma$ in the zero vector of distinct points. Although the imageis zero, they are in distinct tangent planes in $M$

Comment: Do you understand my confusion?

Comment: Yes I understood it and it is wrong, because these are vectors in distinct tangent planes on $M$

Comment: Sorry, I completely misread the definition of immersion! It means each d_t\gamma is injective, which make much more sense! Thanks!

Comment: So isn't this statement I have written in my original question just essentially a rewording?

Answer (score 0):

"$d\gamma$ is injective" just means here that pointwise, it is an injective (*i.e.* nonzero) linear map $T_t J \approx \mathbb{R} \rightarrow T_{\gamma(t)} M.$

The statement is then obvious (since $\gamma'(t) = d\gamma_{|t}(1)$ where $1 = \partial/\partial_t$ under the previous identification)